# "Non-blocking socket operation" error in LWP::UserAgent package of Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, https, lwp

The below code produces an error on Windows 7 Pro, it reads 5-8K bytes of the web page, then terminates:

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/71475421@N02/26176178323/';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->get($url);
print $res->headers->as_string;
```

The error is:

```
X-Died: read failed: A non-blocking socket operation could not be 
completed immediately. at C:/Perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 467.
```

OS: Win 7 Pro (64bit)
Perl: 5.20.1 (32bit)
LWP: 6.08
LWP-Protocols-https: 6.06

Any ideas why is it not working, and how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how useful this is, but:  Your code works for me on CentOS 7, v5.16.  It prints three lines of headers, no warnings or errors.  So it may indeed have something to do with some package on your system. (Btw, I'd suggest that you add `use warnings`.)

Comment: (The immediate cause of the error is `sysread` on the socket returning `EWOULDBLOCK`)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably due to checking only against EAGAIN and not EWOULDBLOCK. These error codes are both the same on most UNIX  but are different on Windows.  I recommend to use a newer version of LWP (at least version 6.09) because there it explicitly deals with this issue and checks for both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

ActivePerl itself (with its outdated LWP package) seems to be the culprit.
Switched to Strawberry Perl and it works like charm.
Dumping ActivePerl...